# How to retrieve the "user input from other file" to display as table in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, quicksort

Below are the example of codes to display the table but how is it to be done when I want to retrieve the information from the user input from other file?

```
package components;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sport",
                                "# of Years",
                                "Vegetarian"};
```

Rather than manually inputting each information, how can I retrieve the information from other file?

```
        **Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe","Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black","Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White","Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown","Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)} };**

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        if (DEBUG) {
            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    printDebugData(table);
                }
            });
        }

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
        int numRows = table.getRowCount();
        int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
        javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

        System.out.println("Value of data: ");
        for (int i=0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j=0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the information about users in a file in csv(comma separated values) format and then use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to parse that file and construct the matrix or array that you use for display.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically your question is how to retrieve the contents of a file into an Object[][]?

Assuming that your file has lines and the lines look like:

```
Kathy,Smith,Snowboarding,5,false
John,Doe,Rowing,3,true
```

that is a CSV file. To read CSV files, your best bet is to download [openCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)
However, if you still want to do it yourself and your data is in a file called "data.csv" I would use a Scanner. Also, assuming you do not know about ArrayLists and stuff like that, here's some code that can get you going.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data.csv"));
int count = 0;
while (s.hasNext())
   count++;
// now count has the number of lines in the file and you know 
// there are 5 attributes.
Object[][] data = new Object[count][5]
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File("data.csv"));
count = 0;
while(s1.hasNext()){
   String[] fields = s1.next().split(",");
   data[count][0] = field[0];
   data[count][1] = fields[1];
   data[count][2] = fields[2];
   data[count][3] = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(fields[3]));
   data[count][4] = new Boolean(fields[4].equals("true");
   count++;   
}
```

Lastly, beware of an indexOutOfBounds error that may happen if you leave empty lines at the beginning, between lines or one line blank at the end (i.e. the last line of your file is empty)